# Do not display property in view

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack

Is there an equivalent of the MVC `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` in ServiceStack?

I do not want a particular model property being displayed in a view.
I have created my own HTML helper extension method to display all property values based on the `System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute` and would like to use an attribute to stop it being displayed.

Here is the view:

```
@inherits ViewPage<GetCustomersubscriptionsResponse>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = string.Format("History >  subscriptions > Customer {0}", Model.CustomerId);
    Layout = "CustomerOfficeUIFabric";
}
<div class="tableContainer">
    @if (Model.subscriptions != null && Model.subscriptions.Count > 0)
    {
        <table class="ms-Table" style="max-width:800px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @{
                        Type subscriptionType = Model.subscriptions.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    }
                    @Html.GenerateHeadings(subscriptionType)
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var subscription in Model.subscriptions)
                {
                    @Html.GenerateRow(subscription)                    
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="notFound ms-font-m-plus">No records found</div>
    }
</div>
```

and here are the extension methods:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GenerateRow(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object Subscription)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<tr>");
        Type SubscriptionType = Subscription.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in SubscriptionType.GetProperties())
        {
            object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(Subscription, null);
            sb.Append($"<td>{propertyValue}</td>");
        }
        sb.Append("</tr>");

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString GenerateHeadings(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Type modelType)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        List<string> displayNames = GetDisplayNames(modelType);

        foreach (var displayName in displayNames)
        {
            sb.Append($"<th>{displayName}</th>");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }

    private static List<string> GetDisplayNames(Type modelType)
    {
        List<string> displayNames = new List<string>();

        PropertyInfo[] props = modelType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {                
            string displayNameAttributeValue = GetDisplayNameAttributeValue(prop);
            string heading = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayNameAttributeValue) ? displayNameAttributeValue : prop.Name;
            displayNames.Add(heading);
        }

        return displayNames;
    }

    private static string GetDisplayNameAttributeValue(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        object[] attributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        if (attributes.Any())
        {
            var displayNameAttributes = attributes.Where(x => x is DisplayNameAttribute);
            if (displayNameAttributes.Any())
            {
                var displayNameAttribute = displayNameAttributes.First() as DisplayNameAttribute;
                return displayNameAttribute.DisplayName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What view are you referring to?

Comment: @mythz I've updated the question.

Comment: ServiceStack doesn’t reference any of these attributes, but I still don’t understand what you’re using to render the view model? Support is going to be dependent on whatever you’re using to render the HTML table.

Comment: @mythz maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but basically I have an endpoint which creates a model, and this model is passed to the view. If that doesn't answer your question, could you provide some examples of things that people could use to render the view model, to help me understand what you're asking.

Comment: and what are you using to render the view model?

Comment: @mythz I'm literally just passing the view model in to the view which then just displays a <tr> element for each property value, sorry I'm obviously not understanding something here. But if ServiceStack doesn't reference any attributes for things like this then maybe I just need to download the MVC nuget package.

Comment: What are you using in your `.cshtml` view to render the HTML table? Can you please update your question with the source code of your `.cshtml` view that renders the table please.

Comment: @mythz please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic would either need to be inside library/functionality you're using to render the HTML table inside the view, e.g:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in SubscriptionType.GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.HasAttribute<HiddenInputAttribute>()) continue;
    //...
}
```

There are also some [Auto Mapping Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) you can use to remove properties you don't want from the View Model.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Public { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string Private { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a new view Model without properties containing the `[HiddenInput]` attribute with:

```
viewModel = new ViewModel().PopulateFromPropertiesWithoutAttribute(
    viewModel, typeof(HiddenInputAttribute));
```

Or you can use [ToObjectDictionary](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary) to manipulate the Model properties in an unstructured dictionary, e.g:

```
var map = viewModel.ToObjectDictionary();
viewModel.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.HasAttribute<HiddenInputAttribute>())
    .Each(x => map.Remove(x.Name)); //remove all props with [HiddenInput]

viewModel = map.FromObjectDictionary<ViewModel>(); //new viewModel without removed props
```